# Unit Testing Bot Framework

Tags: unit-testing, botframework

I'm trying to figure out how to unit test a basic MS Bot Framework dialog and cannot get it to work the way everything on the internet says it should work.

Everything I find basically says follow this:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Tests/Microsoft.Bot.Sample.Tests/EchoBotTests.cs

Well, here's the problem with that:

await Conversation.SendAsync(scope, toBot);

That is defined as internal so it is not accessible outside of the bot.builder code. So it is totally useless unless you are programming tests for internal bot.builder stuff.

Is there a new way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Bot Framework is an open source project, you can download the code and modify it as you need.  In your case removing the `internal` keyword.  Another option would be to create a new class that inherits from the class you are trying to use and making your own access levels on the methods you need to override.  [This blog post](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/07/03/debug-bot-builder-source/) describes how to use the code locally.

Comment: Once you do this what do you suggest for keeping the local code in synch with the latest changes of the Bot Framework? It seems like a really bad idea to do what you are suggesting. If my desire was to modify the Bot Framework internal code I would just change it in GitHub and put in a pull request. That's not what I am asking about here.

Comment: It is not uncommon for people to have their own custom version of the SDK that suits their needs.  However, if you used the inheritance method, you would only have to maintain your own code through new releases of the SDK rather than worrying about the SDK source.  If you find this suggestion to be too burdensome then this is not a good suggestion in your case.

Comment: Burdensome is not what I would call it, I'll leave the word I'd use out of here. Since your a MS engineer do you know if it is Microsoft's intention to not have people use these DialogTestBase classes unless they modify the code in the way you are suggesting? What is the intention Microsoft has? Should we be using the Microsoft Fakes library instead? Does MS have no official opinion or direction on this?

Comment: I think the confusion here is that the testing resources you mention were created for internal testing of botbuilder and the samples included in the repo.  This was not released as "the official bot testing library we expect everyone to use". However, as I mentioned you do have the means to use it as one by using the techniques I described.  I don't understand the aversion to using DialogTest Base in the same manner as it is used in the SDK tests, inheriting from it and customizing a class to test a specific bot functionality.  Are you able to elaborate on why you do not want to do this?