# How to make a set up for unit testing with the bot framework (Echobot, using ITurnContext)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, botframework, moq

I'm trying to make unit tests for an Echobot (just to understand how it works so I can use it for my actual bot), but there is one problem I'm unable to fix. The problem that I'm facing is that I'm using ITurnContext and every example I've come across is using DialogContext (with IWaitable to send the message).
ITurnContext is only readable so I can't set anything into it, unless I do it in the SetUp class which isn't that pretty - but it worked so I continued just to see what would happen and I got an error:

```
Message: Moq.MockException : 
Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: c => c.PostAsync(Mock<Microsoft.Bot.Builder.ITurnContext:00000001>.Object, "You sent 'test'")
No setups configured.
No invocations performed.
```

To begin I used this guide to start: https://medium.com/@createdincode/simple-unit-testing-in-microsofts-c-bot-framework-with-nunit-and-moq-345b805ecd1b
After I ran into some problems I tried searching online and came across this thread: [Auto testing for Microsoft Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348791/auto-testing-for-microsoft-bot-framework) => but the links provided in the top answer all give me a 404..
Same goes for this one [Unit Testing Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50358031/unit-testing-bot-framework), sadly :(

The Test class is currently this:

```
namespace EchoBot.UnitTest
{
    [TestFixture]
    class EchoTest
    {
        private Mock<IChatHelper> _chat;
        private EchoBotBot _echobot;
        private Mock<ITurnContext> _context;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            _chat = new Mock<IChatHelper>();
            _echobot = new EchoBotBot(_chat.Object);

            var activity = new Activity(ActivityTypes.Message);
            activity.Text = "test";

            _context = new Mock<ITurnContext>();

            _context.Setup(c => c.Activity).Returns(activity);
        }

        [Test]
        public async Task echoBackTest()
        {

            await _echobot.OnTurnAsync(_context.Object);

            _chat.Verify(c => c.PostAsync(_context.Object, "You sent 'test'"));

        }

    }
}
```

And the Helper class is the same as the guide I send, except that I changed DialogContext to ITurnContext.
I don't know how to fix this error and I'm afraid of trapping myself inside a Moq hole (if you get what I mean).

I hope I described everything good enough and that somebody can help me! Thanks in advance (:

**EDIT: the code of the EchoBot**

```
public class EchoBotBot : IBot
    {
        private readonly EchoBotAccessors _accessors;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        private IChatHelper _chat;

        public EchoBotBot(IChatHelper chat)
        {
            _chat = chat;
        }

        public EchoBotBot(ConversationState conversationState)
        {
            if (conversationState == null)
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(conversationState));
            }

        }


        public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {

            if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {

                var responseMessage = $"You sent '{turnContext.Activity.Text}'\n";
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(responseMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"{turnContext.Activity.Type} event detected");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you share also `EchoBotBot`?

Comment: Could you `_chat.Verify(c => c.PostAsync(It.IsAny<ITurnContext>(), It.IsAny<string>()));` just to see if there is a problem...

Comment: @Johnny I've recently also tried that, but it gives the same error. I think it's because I'm not really checking a string? I've tried to use `It.IsAny<Activity>()` But this is not allowed because you can't convert a MS.Bot.Schema.Activity to a string
Also I will add the code of EchoBotBot in the post!

Comment: I see at least 2 problems with your code. 1) "You sent 'text'\n" is not equal with "You sent 'text'", 2) you verify wrong method, `chatHelper.PostAsync` instead of  `turnContext.SendActivityAsync`...

Comment: Oh, you're right. I changed the test to this:
```var a = new SimpleAdapter();
            var activity = new Activity(ActivityTypes.Message);
            activity.Text = "test";
            
            var context = new TurnContext(a, activity);

            var response = await context.SendActivityAsync($"You sent '{context.Activity.Text}'\n");

            NUnit.Framework.Assert.IsTrue(response.Id == "You sent 'test'\n");```But I don't think that's correct either, since it doesn't feel like a unit test anymore

Comment: if that is fine I could post the answer as well. just notify if that helped you...

Comment: It still is not working, since I am unable to check the response correctly because the only things I can check on is the id and that's null… Also I cannot use context.SendActivityAsync in the Verify method so I switched to Assert.IsTrue

Comment: What do you want to verify at the end, the result of `SendActivityAsync` or if that method has been called? And yes the way how you changed the tests is not really ok, you created some kind of integration test...

Comment: I want to check if the result is ok (so the "you sent 'test'\n"), I already have response tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your implementation if you want to `Verify` if `SendActivityAsync` has been invoked with the right arguments you could create something like this.

```
//Arrange
var mock = new Mock<ITurnContext>();
mock.Setup(m => m.Activity).Returns(new Activity(ActivityTypes.Message) {Text = "test"});

var sut = new EchoBotBot(Mock.Of<IChatHelper>());

//Act
await sut.OnTurnAsync(mock.Object);

//Assert
mock.Verify(m => m.SendActivityAsync(
    It.Is<string>(msg => msg == "You sent 'test'\n"), 
    null, //or It.IsAny<string>()
    "acceptingInput", //or It.IsAny<string>()
    It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()));
```